# Google Youtube API nextPageToken

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I have read a lot of the other post about using the  `nextPageToken` with the Youtube API.

The reference I am using is

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=100&order=time&videoId=xyvQaVUeu90&fields=items(id%252Csnippet%252FtopLevelComment%252Fsnippet%252FtextDisplay)%252CnextPageToken&_h=35&

The video id i am using is `xyvQaVUeu90`

The script I run returns a nextPageToken as 
`QURTSl9pMm1EbHlJZFdJTENzcHpIMGI3VWllOVl0enBxREN3NlZSYzAzZVdQTkNKNV9XQkpmQTNYLWhhVDIzeGN5eUdXUDZqWUJkdFdBOGdKVksyOENUU3B4b014Yi12Y05PdGRRcVlTaHp3VXEyR0JxRFVYMm5rWG1sbUZsRmk`

So according to the API, if I use that `nextPageToken` it should return the next page of comments, however when I place the `nextPageToken` as the `pageToken`

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=100&order=time&pageToken=QURTSl9pMm1EbHlJZFdJTENzcHpIMGI3VWllOVl0enBxREN3NlZSYzAzZVdQTkNKNV9XQkpmQTNYLWhhVDIzeGN5eUdXUDZqWUJkdFdBOGdKVksyOENUU3B4b014Yi12Y05PdGRRcVlTaHp3VXEyR0JxRFVYMm5rWG1sbUZsRmk&videoId=xyvQaVUeu90&fields=items(id%252Csnippet%252FtopLevelComment%252Fsnippet%252FtextDisplay)%252CnextPageToken&_h=36&

It returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "invalidPageToken",
    "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "pageToken"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token."
 }
}
```

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working perfectly. Just make sure to copy everything between the double quotes ("") . I was able to use it without problems. For example the `nextPageToken` provided in your link is

```
"QURTSl9pMFZuQUJYNGc4dDVZRjRjYlJ3d0M1MlIzeTRSeEJfclZOeEEzdncxRVM4bGZFOXdIRVVVRkJibjBSVW5xaEtBTE1zS0VTd2lDNndrRmJQaG4tY1dScXFral9hMVQ3NmJidFI1Vk83a0xhWEJNU2cwMlYweERGLU1uMDhLazg="
```

but you only copied

```
QURTSl9pMFZuQUJYNGc4dDVZRjRjYlJ3d0M1MlIzeTRSeEJfclZOeEEzdncxRVM4bGZFOXdIRVVVRkJibjBSVW5xaEtBTE1zS0VTd2lDNndrRmJQaG4tY1dScXFral9hMVQ3NmJidFI1Vk83a0xhWEJNU2cwMlYweERGLU1uMDhLazg
```

You did not include `=`